# How to check if date is in a list of date strings?

Tags: python, list, date

This will always print false. How can I check if the date is in the array and print the proper thing?

```
dates = [ "2012-09-03",
"2012-10-08",
"2012-10-09",
"2012-11-12",
# .. more values snipped for brevity
"2013-04-19",
"2013-05-27", ]

if date.today() in dates:
    print "true"
elif date.today() not in dates:
    print "false"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are comparing strings with python `datetime.date` objects; you need to convert the date object to a string for the comparison, using the [`.strftime()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print today in dates # Will print "True" or "False"
```

To illustrate this further:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today()
datetime.date(2012, 8, 28)
>>> date.today() == '2012-08-28'
False
>>> date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == '2012-08-28'
True
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`.isoformat()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat), which uses the exact same output format:

```
>>> date.today().isoformat()
'2012-08-28'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the index() function and the try/except function to test if a date is in your list like so:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
try:
  location = list.index(5)
  print("5 was found in the list.")  # if program manages to get
                                     # here you know 5 is in
                                     # the list.
except:
  print("5 was no found in the list.") # if it doesn't find 5 this
                                       # line is displayed
```