# I am trying to assign a Holiday classifier to a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes, one with a list of dates and their corresponding holiday (df2), and another one with a list of transactions (df1). I'm trying to use the first one to flag holidays on the second one, but whenever I try to create a function and apply it, it just returns empty values for everything.

The function I'm using is as follows:

```
    def isHoliday(t, holiday_list):
        f = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        if(f in (holiday_list)):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

And when I try to apply it:

```
    df1.insert(3, 'isHoliday', df1['DATE'].apply(lambda x: isHoliday(x, 
    df2['DATE'])))
```

The dataframe only returns 0's. I've looked up [date to date comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151488/how-to-check-if-date-is-in-a-list-of-date-strings) and the answer I got from it was to compare them as strings, hence why the function is structured in that way.

What am I doing wrong? I've already preformatted the `df2['DATE']` column as a string with the same `strftime()`

The only direct alternative I can think of is using `df.lookup` from one df to the other, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: can you share samples of the dataframes?

Comment: Try: `df1['isHoliday'] = df1['DATE'].isin(df2['DATE']).astype(int)`, remember to set both date columns to the same format

Comment: Sure. df1 looks like this https://pasteboard.co/IbOSmwX.png
and df2 like this https://pasteboard.co/IbOSZMe.png
The data is in spanish but the same principle applies.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have tried that previously, the hyphen formatting prevents direct int parsing. 

--> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2012-12-31'

Comment: You should post your data sample in codes, not in form of pictures. That helps ppl help you faster :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the if statement to do what you're expecting you need to get a list or a numpy array from the Series returned by the `df2['DATE']` operation. You can either do it by using the `.values` property or converting the series to a list `list(df2['DATE'])`:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2014-01-02'], ['2014-01-03']], columns=['DATE'])
print('2014-01-02' in df2['DATE']) # false
print('2014-01-02' in df2['DATE'].values) # true
print('2014-01-02' in list(df2['DATE'])) # true
```

Alternatively, the `.str.contains()` method can compare all the strings and then `any()` will find if there was a match.

```
any(df2['DATE'].str.contains('2014-01-02', regex=False)) # true
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. Both ways did.

Answer (score 1):

Converting your series to a list should solve your problem:

```
def isHoliday(t, holiday_list):
    f = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if f in list(holiday_list):  # convert series to list
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful, as I realized Series analysis does not have the same properties as list analysis.